# How to fix a non persistent Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have created a slider in an ASP.NET page by using AJAX control Toolkit. To increase and decrease the value of slider, I have also placed a "plus" & a "minus" button. On the client click event of each button I have used a Javascript function that will do some calculations and show it as a `asp:label` below the slider. Now the problem is if I change the value of slider by dragging it, the function is called and the calculations are shown as a label but, if I change the value of the slider by the buttons ("plus" or "minus" button), the function is called but calculations are shown only for couple of seconds as a label. After 1 2 seconds the label is gone, showing nothing.

Does anyone have any idea about my problem?

Here is the code:

1. "Plus" Button:

   ```
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icon_plus1.jpg"
   ```

   style="z-index: 1; left: 830px; top: 130px; position: absolute"
   onclientclick="change1();"/>
2. This is the function that I am calling:

   ```
   function change1() {
      var object = document.getElementById("TextBox");
      var val = object.value;
      object.value = parseInt(val) + 5;
      updatesum();
    }
   ```
3. The main calculation is in the `updatesum()` function:

   ```
   function updatesum() {
   var principal = slider1Value;
   var daily_interest_rate = eval((360 / 100) / 365);
   var transaction_fee = eval(5.50);

   var number_of_days = slider2Value;
   var due_date = addDays(eval(number_of_days)).toDateString();

   var interest_amount = (eval(daily_interest_rate) * eval(number_of_days) *
   eval(eval(principal) + eval(transaction_fee))) + eval(transaction_fee);
   var total_amount = interest_amount + eval(principal);

   lblDate.innerHTML = due_date;
   lblBorrow.innerHTML = "&pound " + slider1Value;
   lblInter.innerHTML = "&pound " + interest_amount.toFixed(2);
   lblRepay.innerHTML = "&pound " + total_amount.toFixed(2);

   }
   ```
4. The Slider and its Target Control ID Textbox:

   ```
   <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender2" runat="server" length="400"
   Enabled="True" Maximum="400" Minimum="0" Steps="80" TargetControlID="TextBox"
   BoundControlID="TextBox1" RailCssClass="SliderRail">
   </ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server" 
   OnChange ="javascript:updatesum(this);"   
   style="z-index: 1; top: 130px; position: absolute; left: 430px; bottom: 130px"
   </asp:TextBox>
   ```

Comment: Fighting with AJAX requests/updates, perhaps? Inspect the network activity to make sure this is [not] the case ..

Comment: Hi, Just added the code. </asp:TextBox> is missing in the code here but its present in the original solution (faced some prob while formatting codes over here, that's why couldn't format this </asp:TextBox>, do not why !! Sorry)

Comment: Got the solution, had to use a hidden textbox to save the input of the label. Thank you all !! :)